# debug android with maven on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, maven

When I create basic Android project on eclipse I can press debug button and get the screen like this:

[image]

It is very comfortable debug screen, I can set the breakpoints, see flow, so on.

But when I am working with Maven project I can get only DDMS window which is not what I like to see. Do someone  know how to make debug window working while deployed with maven android plugin?

Comment: Try this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345740/how-to-debug-android-application-built-with-maven/11345907#11345907

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!!!
Debug button doesn't work, but if manifest file contains debug parameter in manifest file: 
[What do I have to add to the manifest to debug an Android application on an actual Device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409923/what-do-i-have-to-add-to-the-manifest-to-debug-an-android-application-on-an-actu)
so after it launched -> go to DDMS press debug on your process -> then switch on debug perspective and enjoy!!!

Comment: Hey user1504010,
if you found the answer to your own question, go ahead and click the semi-transparent check-mark just to the left of your answer. This will mark the question as answered and will help keep your answer percentage high, which is a good thing here on SO.

Comment: ok thank you for suggestion! I will do it tomorrow, cause impossible answer my own questions same day.

Comment: Do not forget to add -Dandroid.run.debug=true when you are doing mvn android:run if you need to attach the debugger as soon as your application starts.