# Are there any downsides associated with enabling debugging for an Android WebView?

Tags: android, cordova, webview

In an Android WebView, [it is now pretty easy to allow debugging in Chrome on an attached computer](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews). Just add this code and you can debug a WebView just like a page you have open in Chrome:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
}
```

Works great. Wonderful. I'm using it in a Cordova app I'm working on.

My question is, can this cause any problems? Is there any reason I shouldn't leave debugging enabled if I release my app publicly? I presume there must be, otherwise it would just be enabled by default and any WebView would be debuggable. But I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's OK to leave the WebView debugging mode on while your testing and debugging but not when it's live. It would raise a number of risks and open your app to tampering by end users.

You should just extend your Kitkat version condition to include the debug mode from the Manifest file. This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7024481/213519) outlines how to get the debug mode.

It would look something like this:

```
boolean isDebuggable = (0 != ( getApplicationInfo().flags &= ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE));

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && isDebuggable) {
    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Since I'm a complete newb, I can't get that to compile. Am I supposed to be importing anything extra?

Comment: Make sure you have the flag in your Manifest file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409923/what-do-i-have-to-add-to-the-manifest-to-debug-an-android-application-on-an-actu I'm not sure what else. Let me know if you have any more issues. Cheers.

Comment: Doesn't change anything. I have no problem debugging my WebView, it's just that when I add the isDebuggable line it doesn't compile. I'm running `cordova run android` and it fails with these three lines and basically no other info: `BUILD FAILED`, `adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:`, `adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.` (I accepted your answer because this is a different problem than my original question, but I'm still stuck!)

Comment: I don't know any Java, but do I need to be importing `getApplicationInfo` and `ApplicationInfo` from somewhere? Otherwise, what are they? Google wasn't helpful.